# How to limit occurences of the feature in a row in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

How to limit the occurrences of cust_id to 3 in this DataFrame?
I want to limit max to 3 observations of a single client, not more than that.

```
cust_id product
0   112233  mango
1   112233  apple
2   112233  strawberry
3   112233  pineapple
4   112233  chiku
5   123456  grapes
6   123456  apple
7   123456  strawberry
8   123456  pineapple
9   112266  chiku
10  112266  grapes
11  112277  apple
12  112288  strawberry
13  112244  pineapple
14  112244  chiku
```

Comment: `df.groupby('cust_id').head(3)` ? or `df.groupby('cust_id').head(3).reset_index(drop=True)` to fix the index?

Comment: Want to create function to apply large data set , 

Need the Data set not the count.

Comment: Neither of those give the count. `groupby head` will give the first `n` rows per group.

Comment: Perfect, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try with [`groupby head`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.head.html#pandas-core-groupby-groupby-head) to get the first 3 entries per group + optional [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html#pandas-dataframe-reset-index):

```
new_df = df.groupby('cust_id').head(3).reset_index(drop=True)
```

`new_df`:

```
    cust_id     product
0    112233       mango
1    112233       apple
2    112233  strawberry
3    123456      grapes
4    123456       apple
5    123456  strawberry
6    112266       chiku
7    112266      grapes
8    112277       apple
9    112288  strawberry
10   112244   pineapple
11   112244       chiku
```

---

Source DataFrame:

```
    cust_id     product
0    112233       mango
1    112233       apple
2    112233  strawberry
3    112233   pineapple
4    112233       chiku
5    123456      grapes
6    123456       apple
7    123456  strawberry
8    123456   pineapple
9    112266       chiku
10   112266      grapes
11   112277       apple
12   112288  strawberry
13   112244   pineapple
14   112244       chiku
```

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'cust_id': [112233, 112233, 112233, 112233, 112233, 123456, 123456, 123456,
                123456, 112266, 112266, 112277, 112288, 112244, 112244],
    'product': ['mango', 'apple', 'strawberry', 'pineapple', 'chiku', 'grapes',
                'apple', 'strawberry', 'pineapple', 'chiku', 'grapes', 'apple',
                'strawberry', 'pineapple', 'chiku']
})
```